# What’s a word for an organization you’re soliciting a sponsorship from?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

For example:

> *Please enter the name and email of the [word meaning
> a possible sponsor].*

I am building a website that helps users find and
connect with companies and other organizations to ask
them for sponsorships. I am a high schooler in a
robotics club, and part of it is looking for sponsors.
So I’m building a website that automates that process.

However, I can’t think of a word meaning potential
sponsor. I don’t want to write *potential sponsor*
everywhere, as I feel like it’s too verbose, especially
when used in computer code or user interfaces.

So what word could describe someone you’re contacting
in the hope that they’ll become a sponsor of yours? I
considered using just *company*, but that’s not
accurate as sponsors could also include individuals or
families or not-for-profit organizations.

Comment: You could call them ***contacts***, or perhaps ***interested parties***. Even within the specialist field of corporate sponsorship, I doubt there will be any non-jargon terms specifically relevant to *sponsors*, but I guess  ***leads*** might work.

Comment: You've done everything you're supposed to for this kind of question, but I fear you won't find a satisfactory/exact answer. Not everything has a word for it, and English doesn't have any affix that indicates possibility, which greatly reduces the likelihood of there being such a word. Good luck, though.

Comment: Just use "sponsor". Good marketing tactics.

Comment: **prospect** might work. It's a term used in fund-raising to refer to a potential donor.

Comment: It depends on whether the donor or sponsor is entering their own name on a form where they can volunteer. If the word is for "internal" use only, "prospect" is fine.  If the potential donor or sponsor would see it, "prospective sponsor" would be more politic.

Comment: Angel in waiting.